# Error "incompatible types: String cannot be converted to char" when attempting to print

Tags: java, incompatibletypeerror

I create a method for Scanner:

```
public static char getStatus() {
   Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("You are in state student or not(yes for Y/y,no for N/n)");
   char state = kb.nextLine().charAt(0);
   if (state == 'Y'||state == 'y') {
      String instate  = "In State";
      System.out.println(instate);
      int statusfee = 5;
      return instate;
      } else if (state == 'N'||state == 'n') {
      String outstate = "Out-of-State";
      System.out.println(outstate);
      int statusfee = 5+2;
      return outstate;
      } else {
      String false = "FALSE";
      System.out.print(false);
      return false;
     }
   }
```

I try to print out for my choice.
For Example:

```
System.out.println("Residencey:" + state);
```

I want when I type "Y or y"
then the output is Residencey: In State.

And the Errors are:

> error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to char

I don't know why, does java cannot return String or sentence?
I'm a beginner in java, So I cannot use some difficult method.

Comment: `false` is a "reserved word" so to speak so you cannot use it as a variable name

Comment: You have two code paths that return `String`(s) and one that returns a `boolean`. How do you want to use this method?

Comment: Ok, the question is not about "false", it's about how to return the sentence.@ ElliottFrisch

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is `char status = getStatus();`
I think your Class look like:

```
public class ScannerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        char status = getStatus(kb);
        if (status == 'Y') {
            // System.out.println("In State");
        } else if (status == 'N') {

            // System.out.println("Out-of-State");
        } else {
            // System.out.println("FALSE");
        }
        System.out.println("Status is " + status);
    }

    public static char getStatus(Scanner kb) {

        System.out
                .print("You are in state student or not(yes for Y/y,no for N/n)");
        char state = kb.nextLine().charAt(0);
        if (state == 'Y' || state == 'y') {
            String instate = "In State";
            System.out.println(instate);
            int statusfee = 5;
            return 'Y';
        } else if (state == 'N' || state == 'n') {
            String outstate = "Out-of-State";
            System.out.println(outstate);
            int statusfee = 5 + 2;
            return 'N';
        } else {
            String myfalse = "FALSE";
            System.out.print(myfalse);
            return 'F';
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you :)

Comment: JAVA says："error: cannot find symbol" for `public static char getStatus(Scanner kb) { ` and `Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in) `.
symbol:   class Scanner
location: class Test
3 errors

Comment: You need to call like that `Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);` `char status = getStatus(kb);`

Comment: @LeoLin you can modify `getStatus(Scanner kb)`, as you wish :)

Answer (score 0):

your method return type is char and you are returning string that's why it is showing error .
Here is your code with correct return type

```
public static String getStatus () {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print ("You are in state student or not(yes for Y/y,no for N/n)");
    char state = kb.nextLine ().charAt (0);
    if ((state == 'Y') || (state == 'y')) {
        String instate = "In State";
        System.out.println (instate);
        int statusfee = 5;
        return instate;
    } else if ((state == 'N') || (state == 'n')) {
        String outstate = "Out-of-State";
        System.out.println (outstate);
        int statusfee = 5 + 2;
        return outstate;
    } else {
        String FALSE = "FALSE";
        System.out.print (false);
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: And here is a sentence `char status =  getStatus();` is wrong.
same error : incompatible types: String cannot be converted to char
That's in my main method.

Comment: then you have to return Y or N from your getstatus() method. because string has many chars and char can have only one char

Comment: yeah. So the problem is I need `System.out.println("Residencey:" + state);` come to be Residencey: In State. Do you have some suggestions? Just output the sentence like Residencey: In State when I type y or Residencey: Out-of-State when I type n

Comment: At the place where yuo are using 
    char status = getStatus();
use 
    String state= getStatus();
    System.out.println("Residencey:" + state)

Comment: But our requirement is we should use `char status = getStatus();`
our main should look like:`char status = getStatus(kb);` that's the fact.

Comment: what is kb can you explore all the condition in your program

Comment: I don't think kb is important. But kb is keyborad. It's useful in scanner I think.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your method return type to `String`. Example

```
public class ScannerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getStatus();
    }

    public static String getStatus() {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("You are in state student or not(yes for Y/y,no for N/n)");
        char state = kb.nextLine().charAt(0);
        if (state == 'Y' || state == 'y') {
            String instate = "In State";
            System.out.println(instate);
            int statusfee = 5;
            return instate;
        } else if (state == 'N' || state == 'n') {
            String outstate = "Out-of-State";
            System.out.println(outstate);
            int statusfee = 5 + 2;
            return outstate;
        } else {
            String myfalse = "FALSE";
            System.out.print(myfalse);
            return myfalse;
        }
    }
}
```

I changed your variable name.

Comment: The problem is not about false or myfalse.
it's about return.

Comment: Hmm...your answer is same as Ashu, it not works. I tried change char to String.

Comment: could you let me know, what did you expect `getStatus()` return? Y ? N?

Comment: "In State" and "Out-of-State". And if I put Y or y, I can get "In State".
 If I type N or n, I can get "Out-of-State".

Comment: I added next answer, I hope it will help you :) plz check it

Answer (score -3):

### About the error: "incompatible types: String cannot be converted to char"

Type "String", its value can be empty, it can be just one character or a chain of characaters.
Example:

```
String myOneString = "";
String myTwoString = "a";
String myThreeString = "abc";
```

Type 'char', its value can only be one character.
Example:

```
char myCharacter = 'a';
```

the difference at assigning the value is that at assigning type "String" we use doble quotes and at assigning type 'char' we use single quotes.

Comment: True but irrelevant to this question.

Comment: There is more to the question than just the title. I have now edited the title to be more accurate to the question. In the future, please read the entire question when answering.

Comment: Despite the fact that your answer is not correct - with regard to the posted question - according to my understanding of how SO works, an incorrect answer is still considered a valid answer. Note that incorrect answers usually get down-voted.